# jquery animations make ipad hang

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ipad

so i have a script that i wrote to take N images in a gallery and spread them across a div, kind of like an accordion. the script works great on desktop and *most* mobile devices, but the ipad for some reason is very angry with me. about 70% of the time the animation will hang and stop completely.

these are two screengrabs from the ipad. it does not hang in the same place every time 
[image: ipad screenshot 1][image: ipad screenshot 2]

the images are supposed to be evenly spread out, of course, but the animation has hung here. the ipad itself is responsive, and i can switch tabs in safari with no issue.

i was originally not caching my selectors and doing an each() loop to get through every div.galleryItem, and once i switched to cached selectors it works *a little* better...but it still hangs.

here is my javascript that's called on launch:

```
function activateGallery() {
    var n = $('.galleryItem').size(); //number of images in gallery
    var o = Math.round(100/n); //percent to push each image to the left
    var os = 0; //current amount of space on the left
    var z = 1; //z-index
    var d = 0; //duration of animation

    $('#totalSlides').empty().html(pad(n));

    //clean up any open controls
    $('.galleryItem.active > .imageInfoCondensed > .toggle').fadeOut();

    //deactivate active slide if we have one
    $('.galleryItem.active').removeClass("active");

    //NEW ALIGN LOOP WITH CACHED SELECTORS
    var galItems = new Array();
    var galImages = new Array();
    var eq;

    //assign selectors - 1 indexed
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        eq = i - 1;
        galItems[i] = $('.galleryItem:eq(' + eq + ')');
        galImages[i] = $('.galleryImage:eq(' + eq + ')');
    }


    //loop again to spread images
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        galItems[i].animate({
            "marginLeft": os + "%"
        },d).css("zIndex", z);
        os = os + o;
        z++;
        d = d + 200;
    }

    //adjust margins to center pictures
    $(".galleryImage").animate({
        "marginLeft": "-35%"
    },500);

    $('.imageInfoCondensed').delay(d).slideDown(400);

    $('.galleryItem').removeClass("noBorder");
}
```

perhaps i'm not caching the selectors correctly? i'm at a loss here, so any insight would be really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

[CSS3 would be faster for animations than jQuery.](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/) 
Safari is very powerful managing it and should work smother.

If you want it to be compatible with other browsers which does not support CSS3, you could try to make use of [jquery-animate-enhanced](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/) or [something similar](http://addyosmani.com/blog/css3transitions-jquery/).

Also, try to use CSS 3d transform [for a better performance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKl78ZgJzm4). (it will make use of hardware acceleration)
Instead of:

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

Use:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Comment: did some reading just now and this is a GREAT suggestion, thanks! i guess it's time for me to get up to speed on css3.

Comment: "something similar" link is down.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated your best approach is to leverage CSS3 animations and transitions with hardware acceleration

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
     -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

For any animations that require you to use javascript I would look at using `window.requestAnimationFrame` to avoid killing cpu cycles and battery life on mobile devices.

```
// shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();


// usage:
// instead of setInterval(render, 16) ....

(function animloop(){
  requestAnimFrame(animloop);
  render();
})();
// place the rAF *before* the render() to assure as close to
// 60fps with the setTimeout fallback.
```

Paul Irish has a great write up about it here and how to fallback to browsers that do not support it.

http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/